# Is the DF Computer a hoax?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

I heard about the guy who made [a (seemingly)turing complete computer in DF](http://www.bay12forums.com/smf/index.php?topic=49641.0).  Is this serious or is it a hoax?

Answer (score 15):

The Dwarven Computer s real, as can be seen in [this post](http://www.bay12forums.com/smf/index.php?topic=49641.msg1094222#msg1094222) on the Dwarf Fortress forums, which includes a detailed analasys and a link to the [actual save file](http://dffd.wimbli.com/file.php?id=1929) on the Dwarf Fortress Map Archive where you can [preview the map yourself](http://mkv25.net/dfma/map-8269).

Answer (score 2):

I haven't looked at it in depth, but it is certainly possible - there are other similar examples such as creating a turing machine in Conway's Game of Life: http://rendell-attic.org/gol/tm.htm

There are enough mechanisms in DF such as switches with open and closed doors, pumping water and holding it in places etc. for it to be plausible.

Comment: There is also that video of someone making a calculator in LittleBig Planet using ropes and pulleys.

Comment: True.  I know that the game of life is Turing complete.  Interesting aside, Nash proposed that a Universal Constructor needed 17 states.  Conway came up with the game of life in order to show that it could be done with 2.